# Generating pdf from external html file and css

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I have an external html file that I would like to print as a PDF but I'm having trouble getting the example code to work as intended and I'm obviously missing something trivial when implementing it.

This is my code so far:

```
function savePDF(data) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html'); 

    let pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
    pdf.addHTML(
        htmlDoc.body, // HTML DOM element.
    );
    pdf.save("test.pdf");
}
```

Where `data` is a string containing the html of the external webpage I wish to convert to a pdf.

Chrome is generating a TypeError: `Cannot read property 'innerWidth' of null`

This for example works perfectly (using `fromHTML` instead of `addHTML`) but the css/styling is missing:

```
function savePDF(data) {    
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html'); 
    
    let pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
    pdf.fromHTML(htmlDoc.body.innerHTML, 0, 0, {},
        function(){pdf.save('test.pdf');
    });
}
```

Sample html that I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PDF Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
                <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide an example of html data that cause the error?

Comment: @RiccardoGai Added a simple sample html to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says the addHtml method is deprecated ( http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML), so i played a bit with your example and if you updated your code like this it works. You still have to work a bit to fix the width of div in the pdf.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55;">
                        <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
                </div>
            </body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function savePDF(data) {
                    let pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
                    pdf.html(data, {
                       callback: function (doc) {
                         doc.save("test.pdf");
                       }
                    });
                } 
                savePDF(document.body.innerHTML)
            </script>
        </html>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with an external css file. Found an other way of doing it so will mark your answer as accepted as it works with the example html that I provided.